# Microsoft Visual Studio Crash

Tags: visual-studio-2010

after Uninstall visual-studio 2012 visual-studio installed in same machine crashed give me this in event log

---

The description for Event ID 5000 from source Microsoft Visual Studio cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event:

CLR20r3
devenv.exe
10.0.40219.1
4d5f2a73
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common
10.0.40219.457
52601f31
4b6
45
System.MissingMethodException

### the message resource is present but the message is not found in the string/message table

any one can help?

Comment: I've [explained here in detail how to create a dump and analyze it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44312452/1466046). Follow it and analyze what causes the crash

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing Team Foundation libraries, try reinstalling with Team Foundation libraries enabled.