# Visual Studio stops working when trying to debug wp8.1

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, windows-8.1-universal

I'm trying to debug a universal windows 8.1 app on a windows phone 8.1 device but 9/10 times I get an error: Visual Studio has stopped working.
The same happens when I try to connect with Windows Phone Power Tools.

I have

- Windows 10 Enterprise v1511
- Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 v10.0.10586 build 10586
- Nokia Lumia 620 with wp8.1 v8.10.14219.341

I got this from the event viewer:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>100</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-05-12T07:09:21.370709500Z" />
    <EventRecordID>21820</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>eg-lp12044740</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>devenv.exe</Data>
    <Data>14.0.25420.1</Data>
    <Data>57685d85</Data>
    <Data>unknown</Data>
    <Data>0.0.0.0</Data>
    <Data>00000000</Data>
    <Data>c0000005</Data>
    <Data>00010010</Data>
    <Data>1bec</Data>
    <Data>01d2caeddcdbb565</Data>
    <Data>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe</Data>
    <Data>unknown</Data>
    <Data>0a49c40f-360f-436e-afdc-c57c786e3957</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: c0000005 = access violation. [Create a crash dump](https://pastebin.com/zKuJvw57) and analyze dmp in Windbg.exe (part of Win10 SDK) by running **!analyze -v**. Also update your Windows, you use the older 1511 version, try 1607 or 1703

Comment: @tomcoaly, Do you get any messages in the output window? If you debug your app using "start without debugging(Ctrl+F5)", how about the result? Whether all projects have the same issue? Please also delete the bin /obj folder, and then re-open your project, or restart your device, check it again. In addition, I suggest you disable the symbols Server under TOOLS->Options->Debugging->Symbols, and pay more attentions to the build platforms which are different (x86 vs. ARM).

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT Thank you! I don't get any messages in output. It seems like if I use the Start without debugging button first, then I can start the debugging. I didn't try it with other solutions, but WP Power tools does the same thing, so I guess the problem isn't with the project. I tried deleting the bin/obj before with no help. Disabling symbol server didn't help. Platform is correct (ARM).

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thank you! Unfortunately I don't have rights to update windows because I use corporate computer.

Comment: ask your IT to rollup at least 1607. also try to create dumps and analyze them

Comment: I've [explained here in detail how to create a dump and analyze it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44312452/1466046). Follow it and analyze what causes the crash