# visual studio crashing if tried to launch xamarin.windows on device

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, windows-mobile, xamarin.windows, xamarin.winphone

I was able to run my xamarin.windows project in device earlier but suddenly I am getting this problem that is whenever I try to run the app on device its crashing the visual studio.Please find the screenshot below

[image: Visual studio crash image]

List of things I tried sofar:

- Removed and added the nugget packages
- devenv resetuserdata
- Removing and readding the windows developer license

Nothing worked so far

Here is the eventviewer error log:

[image: eventviewer error log]

Comment: [generate a crash dump](https://pastebin.com/zKuJvw57) and analyze it (**!analyze -v**) with windbg.exe (part of Windows SDK/Debugging tools)

Comment: Please find the event viewer error log.. it really doesn't give much clue

Comment: this doesn't help, generate a crash dump and analyze it in windbg

Comment: I will try that

Comment: any progress? have you captured a dump? were you able to analyze it?

Comment: I've [explained here in detail how to create a dump and analyze it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44312452/1466046). Follow it and analyze what causes the crash

Comment: @magicandre1981 - Thanks I will look into that