# Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 has stopped working - after computer sleep

Tags: crash, windows-8.1, visual-studio-2017

My visual studio keeps crashing **after waking up my computer from sleep**.

Spectacular is that sometimes it **blocks mouse and keyboard**. Mouse moves in a speed of few pixels every 5 seconds, for pressed key on the keyboard you wait like 10 seconds. Highly unusual, because mouse and keyboard have usually the highest priority no matter what happens. With parallelly installed VS2015 and VS2013 there is no problem (therefore I suppose it is not caused by Resharper).

Program and system info:

- VS Community 2017, Version 15.2 (26430.12)
- Using Resharper Ultimate 2017.1.2
- OS: Windows 8.1 Pro, Version 6.3.9600

---

**Edit:**
By following the suggestion about [writing and reading crash dump by WinDbg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44312452/2094687) I got this error description (memory corruption there is frightening ...). Any further suggestion will be appreciated.

```
    *******************************************************************************
    *                                                                             *
    *                        Exception Analysis                                   *
    *                                                                             *
    *******************************************************************************

    *** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for mscorlib.ni.dll
    *** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for PresentationFramework.ni.dll
    *** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for WindowsBase.ni.dll
    *** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0.ni.dll
    *** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for System.ni.dll
    *** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Features.ni.dll
    *** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.ni.dll
    *** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.Text.ni.dll
    *** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for Microsoft.Build.ni.dll
    *** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for libleveldb.dll - 
    *** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.ni.dll
    *** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for System.Runtime.Remoting.ni.dll
    DEBUG_FLR_EXCEPTION_CODE(80131509) and the ".exr -1" ExceptionCode(e0434352) don't match

    DUMP_CLASS: 2

    DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

    CONTEXT:  (.ecxr)
    eax=55f9e8c0 ebx=00000005 ecx=00000005 edx=00000000 esi=55f9e980 edi=00000001
    eip=760f2f71 esp=55f9e8c0 ebp=55f9e918 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz ac pe nc
    cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000216
    KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x48:
    760f2f71 8b4c2454        mov     ecx,dword ptr [esp+54h] ss:002b:55f9e914=ee800b58
    Resetting default scope

    FAULTING_IP: 
    KERNELBASE!RaiseException+48
    760f2f71 8b4c2454        mov     ecx,dword ptr [esp+54h]

    EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
    ExceptionAddress: 760f2f71 (KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x00000048)
       ExceptionCode: e0434352 (CLR exception)
      ExceptionFlags: 00000001
    NumberParameters: 5
       Parameter[0]: 80131509
       Parameter[1]: 00000000
       Parameter[2]: 00000000
       Parameter[3]: 00000000
       Parameter[4]: 715a0000

    PROCESS_NAME:  devenv.exe

    ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xe0434352 - 

    EXCEPTION_CODE: (HRESULT) 0x80131509 (2148734217) - 

    EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  80131509

    EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  80131509

    EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  00000000

    EXCEPTION_PARAMETER3:  00000000

    EXCEPTION_PARAMETER4: 0

    WATSON_BKT_PROCSTAMP:  59275f23

    WATSON_BKT_PROCVER:  15.0.26430.12

    PROCESS_VER_PRODUCT:  Microsoft® Visual Studio®

    WATSON_BKT_MODULE:  KERNELBASE.dll

    WATSON_BKT_MODSTAMP:  53eeb460

    WATSON_BKT_MODOFFSET:  12f71

    WATSON_BKT_MODVER:  6.3.9600.17278

    MODULE_VER_PRODUCT:  Microsoft® Windows® Operating System

    BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  6.3.9600.17056 (winblue_gdr.140319-1520)

    DETOURED_IMAGE: 1

    MODLIST_WITH_TSCHKSUM_HASH:  fb123f85e82dc66a6aaa47baaf54a8d6c688d06a

    MODLIST_SHA1_HASH:  5d338567fc7fda41c0d3a856681d67a8a2273337

    NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

    PROCESS_BAM_CURRENT_THROTTLED: 0

    PROCESS_BAM_PREVIOUS_THROTTLED: 0

    APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

    CHKIMG_EXTENSION: !chkimg -lo 50 -d !KERNELBASE
        760ed598-760ed59c  5 bytes - KERNELBASE!GetModuleHandleW
        [ 8b ff 55 8b ec:e9 20 3c 57 eb ]
        760edbce-760edbd2  5 bytes - KERNELBASE!GetModuleHandleExW (+0x636)
        [ 8b ff 55 8b ec:e9 41 34 57 eb ]
        760f1bc6-760f1bca  5 bytes - KERNELBASE!RegCloseKey (+0x3ff8)
        [ 8b ff 55 8b ec:e9 84 47 94 8a ]
        760f213e-760f2142  5 bytes - KERNELBASE!RegQueryValueExW (+0x578)
        [ 8b ff 55 8b ec:e9 8c 42 94 8a ]
        760f2441-760f2445  5 bytes - KERNELBASE!RegOpenKeyExW (+0x303)
        [ 8b ff 55 8b ec:e9 2d 3a 94 8a ]
        760f30c6-760f30ca  5 bytes - KERNELBASE!FreeLibrary (+0xc85)
        [ 8b ff 55 8b ec:e9 9c e1 56 eb ]
        760f30f4-760f30f8  5 bytes - KERNELBASE!LoadLibraryExW (+0x2e)
        [ 8b ff 55 8b ec:e9 52 e4 56 eb ]
        760f772e-760f7732  5 bytes - KERNELBASE!RegOpenKeyExA (+0x463a)
        [ 8b ff 55 8b ec:e9 e8 f1 93 8a ]
        760f7e99-760f7e9d  5 bytes - KERNELBASE!RegQueryValueExA (+0x76b)
        [ 8b ff 55 8b ec:e9 1c ea 93 8a ]
        760fa5b1-760fa5b5  5 bytes - KERNELBASE!RegCreateKeyExW (+0x2718)
        [ 8b ff 55 8b ec:e9 45 c4 93 8a ]
        760fe5b7-760fe5bb  5 bytes - KERNELBASE!RegCreateKeyExA (+0x4006)
        [ 8b ff 55 8b ec:e9 75 e7 93 8a ]
        76100273-76100279  7 bytes - KERNELBASE!RegQueryInfoKeyW (+0x1cbc)
        [ 6a 48 68 d0 03 10 76:e9 2d 65 93 8a cc cc ]
        7610049e-761004a4  7 bytes - KERNELBASE!RegDeleteValueW (+0x22b)
        [ 6a 20 68 28 05 10 76:e9 e6 83 93 8a cc cc ]
        76100fd0-76100fd6  7 bytes - KERNELBASE!RegEnumValueW (+0xb32)
        [ 6a 38 68 f8 10 10 76:e9 7d 58 93 8a cc cc ]
        76102ad4-76102ad8  5 bytes - KERNELBASE!RegEnumKeyExA (+0x1b04)
        [ 68 58 02 00 00:e9 09 6e 93 8a ]
        76106c9a-76106c9e  5 bytes - KERNELBASE!RegEnumKeyExW (+0x41c6)
        [ 8b ff 55 8b ec:e9 45 fb 92 8a ]
        7610b27e-7610b284  7 bytes - KERNELBASE!RegEnumValueA (+0x45e4)
        [ 6a 60 68 08 b5 10 76:e9 21 fe 96 8a cc cc ]
        7611f3f4-7611f3fa  7 bytes - KERNELBASE!RegQueryInfoKeyA (+0x14176)
        [ 6a 60 68 88 f5 11 76:e9 1b bd 95 8a cc cc ]
        7612107a-7612107e  5 bytes - KERNELBASE!RegDeleteKeyExW (+0x1c86)
        [ 8b ff 55 8b ec:e9 5f 66 91 8a ]
        7612489c-761248a2  7 bytes - KERNELBASE!RegDeleteValueA (+0x3822)
        [ 6a 20 68 30 49 12 76:e9 c6 67 95 8a cc cc ]
        7617240a-7617240e  5 bytes - KERNELBASE!RegDeleteKeyExA (+0x4db6e)
        [ 8b ff 55 8b ec:e9 ed 8b 90 8a ]
    117 errors : !KERNELBASE (760ed598-7617240e)

    PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

    SUITE_MASK:  272

    DUMP_FLAGS:  8000c07

    DUMP_TYPE:  3

    MISSING_CLR_SYMBOL: 0

    MANAGED_EXCEPTION_HRESULT: 80131509

    ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  KOMP

    ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  06-11-2017 08:17:44.0657

    ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.15063.400 x86fre

    MANAGED_CODE: 1

    MANAGED_ENGINE_MODULE:  clr

    MANAGED_ANALYSIS_PROVIDER:  SOS

    MANAGED_THREAD_ID: c44

    MANAGED_EXCEPTION_ADDRESS: 905fdb68

    LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 716f0245 to 760f2f71

    THREAD_ATTRIBUTES: 
    FAULTING_THREAD:  ffffffff

    THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  8b084063f74c10f14fd5a9c68991db600ea504a6

    THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  ba90ca3a69862e0865ec0206bec2d1add0fdbffe

    ADDITIONAL_DEBUG_TEXT:  SOS.DLL is not loaded for managed code. Analysis might be incomplete ; Followup set based on attribute [Is_ChosenCrashFollowupThread] from Frame:[0] on thread:[PSEUDO_THREAD]

    OS_LOCALE:  ENU

    PROBLEM_CLASSES: 

        ID:     [0n237]
        Type:   [CLR_EXCEPTION]
        Class:  Primary
        Scope:  DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID (Failure Bucket ID prefix)
                BUCKET_ID
        Name:   Add
        Data:   Omit
        PID:    [Unspecified]
        TID:    [0xc44]
        Frame:  [0] : KERNELBASE!RaiseException

        ID:     [0n235]
        Type:   [@ManagedObjectName]
        Class:  Addendum
        Scope:  DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID (Failure Bucket ID prefix)
                BUCKET_ID
        Name:   Omit
        Data:   Add
                String: [System.InvalidOperationException]
        PID:    [Unspecified]
        TID:    [Unspecified]
        Frame:  [0]

        ID:     [0n203]
        Type:   [MEMORY_CORRUPTION]
        Class:  Primary
        Scope:  DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID (Failure Bucket ID prefix)
                BUCKET_ID
        Name:   Add
        Data:   Omit
        PID:    [0x988]
        TID:    [0xc44]
        Frame:  [Unspecified]

        ID:     [0n151]
        Type:   [PATCH]
        Class:  Addendum
        Scope:  DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID (Failure Bucket ID prefix)
                BUCKET_ID
        Name:   Add
        Data:   Omit
        PID:    [0x988]
        TID:    [0xc44]
        Frame:  [Unspecified]

        ID:     [0n234]
        Type:   [NOSOS]
        Class:  Addendum
        Scope:  DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID (Failure Bucket ID prefix)
                BUCKET_ID
        Name:   Add
        Data:   Omit
        PID:    [Unspecified]
        TID:    [Unspecified]
        Frame:  [0]

    BUGCHECK_STR:  CLR_EXCEPTION_System.InvalidOperationException_NOSOS_MEMORY_CORRUPTION_PATCH

    DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  CLR_EXCEPTION_System.InvalidOperationException_NOSOS_MEMORY_CORRUPTION_PATCH

    PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  CLR_EXCEPTION

    STACK_TEXT:  
    00000000 00000000 memory_corruption!KERNELBASE+0x0


    STACK_COMMAND:  !sos.pe 0x905fdb68 ; ** Pseudo Context ** ; kb

    THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  7da7fbec386ce361a40d03d69a994bc4836f03e8

    SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  0

    SYMBOL_NAME:  memory_corruption!KERNELBASE

    FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

    MODULE_NAME: memory_corruption

    DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0

    FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  CLR_EXCEPTION_System.InvalidOperationException_NOSOS_MEMORY_CORRUPTION_PATCH_80131509_memory_corruption!KERNELBASE

    BUCKET_ID:  CLR_EXCEPTION_System.InvalidOperationException_NOSOS_MEMORY_CORRUPTION_PATCH_DETOURED_memory_corruption!KERNELBASE

    FAILURE_EXCEPTION_CODE:  80131509

    IMAGE_NAME:  memory_corruption

    FAILURE_IMAGE_NAME:  memory_corruption

    BUCKET_ID_IMAGE_STR:  memory_corruption

    FAILURE_MODULE_NAME:  memory_corruption

    BUCKET_ID_MODULE_STR:  memory_corruption

    FAILURE_FUNCTION_NAME:  KERNELBASE

    BUCKET_ID_FUNCTION_STR:  KERNELBASE

    BUCKET_ID_OFFSET:  0

    BUCKET_ID_MODTIMEDATESTAMP:  0

    BUCKET_ID_MODCHECKSUM:  0

    BUCKET_ID_MODVER_STR:  0.0.0.0

    BUCKET_ID_PREFIX_STR:  CLR_EXCEPTION_System.InvalidOperationException_NOSOS_

    FAILURE_PROBLEM_CLASS:  CLR_EXCEPTION

    FAILURE_SYMBOL_NAME:  memory_corruption!KERNELBASE

    WATSON_STAGEONE_URL:  http://watson.microsoft.com/StageOne/devenv.exe/15.0.26430.12/59275f23/KERNELBASE.dll/6.3.9600.17278/53eeb460/80131509/00012f71.htm?Retriage=1

    TARGET_TIME:  2017-06-10T19:22:40.000Z

    OSBUILD:  9600

    OSSERVICEPACK:  17056

    SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

    OS_REVISION: 0

    OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x86

    OSNAME:  Windows 8.1

    OSEDITION:  Windows 8.1 WinNt SingleUserTS

    USER_LCID:  0

    OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  2014-03-20 00:55:24

    BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  140319-1520

    BUILDLAB_STR:  winblue_gdr

    BUILDOSVER_STR:  6.3.9600.17056

    ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME:  9ad5

    ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  UM

    FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  um:clr_exception_system.invalidoperationexception_nosos_memory_corruption_patch_80131509_memory_corruption!kernelbase

    FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {1100017e-170d-400c-940f-f475e873df74}

    Followup:     MachineOwner
    ---------
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I diagnose and fix a Visual Studio 2015 crash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43850977/how-do-i-diagnose-and-fix-a-visual-studio-2015-crash)

Comment: apply the settings in my answer to get a full dump and analyze it with Windbg as I explained it.

Comment: Thank you @magicandre1981, I followed your instructions, created dump and attached its results to the question. Still do not know, how to handle and what is causing the problem.

Comment: you have memory corruptions in KERNELBASE.dll. So the file is either damaged on disk or gets corrupted in memory. so test memory first with memtest86, if this is fine, run chkdsk to detect ntfs issues and if this is fine run sfc  and DISM to detect and repair corrupted files.

Comment: also this **_DETOURED_** could man you run a software that hooks kernel32/kernelbase dlls to modify Windows functions and replace them. use msconfig/autoruns to isolate which 3rd party tool may hook the DLL if all system files are fine and memory is fine

Comment: any update on your issue?

Comment: I doubt .... clear cache in Resharper sometimes helps me.  I am not sure if it is related to https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000895579-ReSharper-broken-with-Visual-Studio-2017-15-8-5-update-