# Visual Studio 2017 crashed after changing text zoom

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Several issues releted to zoom in VS 2017 text editor. Actually, I don't know if problem has started right after installation or later since I haven't used zoom function before.

1. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + scrolling doesn't work and result in [window prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ip8K.png) (then text just goes 3 lines down and up)
2. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> results in 
   [another window prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oq1dK.png)
3. Selecting any value in the combo box leads to VS crash with a message like this:

   ```
   Problem signature:
   Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
   Problem Signature 01:   devenv.exe
   Problem Signature 02:   15.0.26403.7
   Problem Signature 03:   58f0354e
   Problem Signature 04:   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0
   Problem Signature 05:   15.0.26403.7
   Problem Signature 06:   58f032e2
   Problem Signature 07:   1e28
   Problem Signature 08:   18
   Problem Signature 09:   System.UnauthorizedAccess
   OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.49
   Locale ID:  1045
   Additional Information 1:   0a9e
   Additional Information 2:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
   Additional Information 3:   0a9e
   Additional Information 4:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
   ```

Comment: I would suggest you report this to Microsoft, I don't know if SO is the place to solve such crashes. VS2017 is still (fairly) new, so it may be a bug.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I diagnose and fix a Visual Studio 2015 crash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43850977/how-do-i-diagnose-and-fix-a-visual-studio-2015-crash)

Comment: System.UnauthorizedAccess = access denied. look at the dump or also run ProcessMonitor and look which operation of devenv.exe fails with access denied

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue.

Deleting the folder below solved the issue for me.

C:\Users\Your_user_name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.xxxxx