# IE crashes Visual studio on page refresh

Tags: debugging, typescript, visual-studio-2015, internet-explorer-11

This may be typescript related, but my VS2015 has started crashing since last one week. It happens when I start my angular 2 application in the debug mode and try to refresh IE or try to navigate away to some other site. I've tried deleting .map files with no luck.

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: devenv.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 14.0.25420.1
  Problem Signature 03: 57685d85
  Problem Signature 04: TypeScriptDebugEngine
  Problem Signature 05: 14.30615.1.0
  Problem Signature 06: 5761ce48
  Problem Signature 07: 7a
  Problem Signature 08: c
  Problem Signature 09: System.NullReferenceException
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    3081
  Additional Information 1: 997a
  Additional Information 2: 997a385fd192aa9a5847e00a1a4b4316
  Additional Information 3: 84b3
  Additional Information 4: 84b3ddebe26c33e3c11db3318feab1a1
```

Comment: Almost all Visual Studio problems can be solved by clearing out your component cache. Although this article is about a different problem, the fix helps with lots of other ones too. https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2015/11/how-to-fix-broken-intellisense-in-visual-studio-razor-views/

Comment: Just tried. Still having the same issue.

Comment: @Sam, run VS in safe mode( devenv.exe /safemode), how about the result? Not really debug your app, if you just run your app using "start without debugging(Ctrl+F5)", how about the result? Of course, if you have other clean VS Environment, please also debug the same app, at least, we could know that whether it is related to the project itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I diagnose and fix a Visual Studio 2015 crash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43850977/how-do-i-diagnose-and-fix-a-visual-studio-2015-crash)

Comment: check my answer in duplicate question on how to create a crash dump and analyze it in Windbg/DebugDiag

Comment: So I've updated the TypeScript to version 2 (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48593) and it seems to have resolved the issue for me. Thanks a lot everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've updated the TypeScript to version 2 (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48593) and it seems to have resolved the issue for me.

Comment: how did you detect this? Trial&error or does it show in the dump?

Comment: @Sam, Since it was resolved, you could mark your reply as the answer. Thanks for your sharing.