# Visual Studio 2017 stops and then restarts when i try to run the UWP app

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, uwp-xaml

I'm using visual studio 2017, currently i'm developing UWP apps I don't know the exact reason, when i try to run the application it suddenly stops and closes and then restarts again and also some times i get the Microsoft Visual Studio is busy message as a notification and visual studio got stucked. Can any one help me to solve this issues.

[image: Visual Studio restarts like as shown in this figure]

Comment: looks like the compiler might be crashing. What version are you running?

Comment: VS will write logs which you can read to further drill down on possible causes.  I cannot remember offhand where they are created but I think it's in the Appdata folders.

Comment: create a crash dump and analyze the dump as I've explained in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44312452/1466046)

Comment: My Visual Studio version: 15.2(26430.16) @Takarii