# visual studio 2015 crashes sometimes if we scroll .xaml file

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, windows-8, xamarin.winphone

I am using visual studio 2015 on windows 8 to develop xamarin mobile apps.
When I scroll .xaml page in visual studio, the visual studio crashes sometimes with the following errors

[image]

[image]

When I try to reopen visual studio again I am getting the following errors and visual studio never open till I restart the system

[image]

[image]

How to fix the problem ?

Comment: Looks like nothing xamarin specific. Please search online for suggestions. One of them https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2017/06/failed-to-load-penimc-dll-and-related-problems/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I diagnose and fix a Visual Studio 2015 crash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43850977/how-do-i-diagnose-and-fix-a-visual-studio-2015-crash)

Comment: @YuriS - I am looking for some solution other than uninstalling the latest update

Comment: do what I wrote in my answer in the duplicate (create crash dumps and analyze the dump in debugdiag or windbg)

Comment: ok, looks like this a bug in .net 4.7. Apply the [last Rollup](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/07/24/net-framework-july-2017-preview-of-quality-rollup/) + the [fix for an issue](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/07/25/net-framework-july-2017-quality-update/)