# unable to uninstall/repare/modify visual studio 2013 getting vs2013 has stopped working error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Today i am trying to uninstall visual studio 2013 on my windows 7 PC when ever i click on change option in programs and features it goes to visual studio stopped working error window i even tried with the setup file as well its same with that as well tried the total uninstaller mentioned @ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt720585.aspx Still no luck

tried Revo Uninstaller as well its of no use

I tried disabling .Net Framework 3.5 no go uninstalled 4.5 no go re enabled 3.5 no go

So now i want to uninstall the VS2013 but have no idea how to do it

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I diagnose and fix a Visual Studio 2015 crash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43850977/how-do-i-diagnose-and-fix-a-visual-studio-2015-crash)

Comment: [generate a crash dump of devenv.exe and analyze](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44312452/1466046) the dump

Comment: have you created and analyzed the dump?

Comment: Nope I just reinstalled my OS and freshly installed Studio

Comment: ok, post this as answer and accept it later

Answer (score 0):

Try to download this tool **TotalUninstaller.zip** from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller/releases).

Perform these steps to complete uninstall Visual Studio:

- Extract *.zip* file
- Open an administrator command prompt
- Execute **Setup.ForcedUninstall.exe**
- Type **'Y'** to uninstall

Comment: As you can see the link i provided in the question is for downloading the Total installer and it is not working it gives me same Setup.ForcedUninstall.exe has stopped working window

Comment: run it as administrator

Comment: It didn't work that way as well finally i reinstalled my OS and freshly installed Studio into it