# Visual Studio Crashes on deployment of windows phone project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, deployment, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing a windows phone 8.1 application. Visual Studio is crashing almost all the time I try to deploy the project on a real device. I am currently using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013: update 5. Is there any good solution to this problem? This is really frustrating.

Comment: Use vs2015 with win phone 8.1 sdk, may be problem in your system or something missing, so may be vs2015 also so it will also show stop working your reinstall your windows. If this error comes on vs 2015 also

Comment: That is not much of a solution. Thanks, anyways.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I diagnose and fix a Visual Studio 2015 crash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43850977/how-do-i-diagnose-and-fix-a-visual-studio-2015-crash)

Comment: create a [crash dump and analyze the dump with windbg/debugdiag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44312452/1466046) to see the cause