# Visual Studio 2015 "...has stopped working" when trying to install

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Trying to install 'Visual Studio 2015 with Update 3' using the .exe installer provided for the [visualstudio.com](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/older-downloads/) website.  I also tried the standard version (without the update).

The black/grey installer opens, the green bar moves along the progress bar once and it crashes.  I get a white pop-up window saying 'Microsoft Visual Studio Community with Updates has stopped working'.

[image]

I can't seem to find any other situations like mine on Google or StackOverflow.

I have Visual Studio 2017 also installed. Why do I need 2015 too? I'm helping (trying) another student who is using VS2015 and has problems - however, I can't even get it downloaded!

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: To clarify - you don't already have 2015 installed?  Have you ever had it installed before?  One thing to try might be installed 2015 VS Express instead (there are 2 or 3 different versions).  The main thing you'll miss in express is you can't install extensions.

Comment: Visual Studio dumps a whole bunch of log files in your `%temp%` directory, one of them is the main log file which may give you a hint to which component is causing the problems.

Comment: @LightCC I have never had VS2015 installed before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I diagnose and fix a Visual Studio 2015 crash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43850977/how-do-i-diagnose-and-fix-a-visual-studio-2015-crash)

Comment: [Analyze the crashes with windbg/debugdiag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44312452/1466046).

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to not worry about 2015 and just help him by using 2017.  It's hard to tell for sure if this will resolve your issue, as there is not info on exactly what you are trying to help him with.

If you go this route, I would save out the solution file just after loading it with `_vs2017` tacked on the end, or something similar, so that you do not overwrite the info in his solution file.  (*Edit:* The purpose of this is just in case it breaks something for him - it may not be a problem, he may be able to load your 2017 solution file fine).  I've moved fluidly between 2017 Community and 2015 Express or Community with some solutions without a problem.

I do realize there are some issues that this may not be a solution for, but it should be an option, especially for those that are more language-based.  The main problems with this solution would be if other student is using features or libraries that are deprecated in 2017, or directly struggling with getting VS 2015 features to work.

Comment: VS2017 and VS2015 will actually round-trip for quite a few types of projects.

Answer (score 0):

Go to control Panel -> Programs and features -> turn on windows features ,

Disable .net 3.5

check for windows update,

Then restart the system. Now it will work . 100% working .

Have fun.