# Visual studio crashes on some of the designer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, inheritance, crash

I have visual studio 2013(with update 5) which uses `MetroFramework` to set it styles, in this program, I have multiple screens and which most of inherits from some base screen

All the screen that does not inherits from the base screen(including the base screen itself), their designer works fine, but those who are inherit from the base screen crashes the IDE

Sometimes" i can the error: "object reference not set to an instance of an object" and then the IDE crashed
I already tried to(and none help):

1. Re-Install Visual Studio
2. remove extension and/or NuGet package(s)
3. Delete .suo file
4. Using devneve.exe reset commands(like `resetuserdata`)
5. Loading the IDE with safe mode or admin mode

viewing the dump or and/or devenv /log did not yield  any useful information

I do think that it's something in my code, but I don't know to get the bottom of it

P.S

the program working just fine when viewing/working with those screens

Comment: Did you try attaching to Visual Studio process with a debugger from another Visual Studio instance?

Comment: create a [crash dump and analyze the dmp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44312452/1466046)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **attaching** to the Visual Studio process from another VS instance. **Observe** the **Event Viewer** when recreating this issue to see if the errors there can give you more information, try and **updating your Visual Studio** to the latest version 2017 as this bug may have been patched or fixed in a stable update:

[***visualStudio.microsoft.com/***](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/)

Answer (score 1):

I have to vouch for VS 2017, I have a ton of code in 2013 and 2015 and fought moving to a new version in fear it would break things.  I haven't had a single issue, over 50 large apps have been ported in no problem.  The only issue that I have seen has been compact framework, and I'm sure that's because I don't have something loaded, however we have dropped it.

Another thing is I originally installed VS 2017 and it installed separately and let 2015 still run with no interference.  About 3 months later I copied source code to new folders and loaded them into 2017 with no problems.  I run vs 2017 pro and pay the $45 per month, https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/pricing/ cheaper and lots of add on components.

There are plenty of articles on metro framework and VS2017.

I'm only saying all of this because I fought hard not to upgrade then a lot of my problems went away once I did.