# Devenv.exe crash after running "Devenv.exe /setup" command

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions

I'm facing a problem in Visual Studio 2019 when run "Devenv.exe /setup". The below error appears:

```
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 16.4.29519.181, time stamp: 0x5dd4c41f
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.18362.476, time stamp: 0x540698cd
Exception code: 0xc0020001
Fault offset: 0x001135d2
Faulting process id: 0x1fd4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d5ac2ab285da4c
Faulting application path: c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 1c8317ca-dfc3-445e-be84-8b7a19b32f6c
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: 

Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 16.4.29519.181, time stamp: 0x5dd4c41f
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.18362.476, time stamp: 0x540698cd
Exception code: 0xc000041d
Fault offset: 0x001135d2
Faulting process id: 0x1fd4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d5ac2ab285da4c
Faulting application path: c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 1047e34b-363a-4ecd-af5f-de8a84c1e04d
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

I need this to add extension to Visual Studio menu.
The problem happens for VisualStudio 2019, for both versions 16.3.8 and 16.4.0 which is the last update.

Please advice!

Comment: analyze [a crash dump](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44312452/1466046). If you can't understand the dumps, [submit the crash to Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) and [attach the dmps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#record-a-repro) to the report

Comment: Hi, did you have detailed error message? Or you can try to delete all the component cache under `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_5131b69d\ComponentModelCache` and then try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need this to add extension to Visual Studio menu. The problem
>   happens for VisualStudio 2019, for both versions 16.3.8 and 16.4.0
>   which is the last update.

Still l am not sure about what does `devenv.exe crash` means.
Besides, as the document said like this:

```
devenv /setup
```

***Forces Visual Studio to merge resource metadata that describes menus, toolbars, and command groups from all available VSPackages. You can only run this command as an administrator.
This switch takes no arguments. The devenv /Setup command is typically given as the last step of the installation process. Use of the /Setup switch doesn't start the IDE.***

**Note** this means you should first run [Developer Command Prompt for VS2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs#search-for-the-command-prompt-on-your-machine) as Administrator.(right-click on it and choose Administrator)

Then type devenv / setup to force Visual Studio to merge resource metadata that describes menus, toolbars, and command groups from all available VSPackages. This will not invoke instance of VS IDE and after that you can start VS.

If you run this command and then the command prompt exits immediately, please try this steps:

1) clean all the files under the path `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_5131b69d\ComponentModelCache`

2) [do a repair](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) in vs installer

Hope it could help you.