# Visual studio crashes and reboot it self when i'm using quick watch

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Visual studio times out our reboot when i'm using quick watch in a window in debug mode. It can start with that all the text in quick watch disappears and after a few seconds VS 2019 freeze and reboots. It does it every time depends on how long i use quick watch.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019.

Is this a common problem or do i use quick watch wrong?

Comment: Make sure VS is up to date. If it is, you can report a problem using the "Send Feedback" button--to the right on the VS tool bar.

Comment: Please, share error details, event logs and so on

Comment: [generate a VS crash dump](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44312452/1466046) and analyze the dump