# postmortem debugging for chromium crashes on windows?

Tags: google-chrome, windbg

Is there any way to do postmortem debugging for chrome(or chromium) with windbg??

I tried to do these steps

1. install postmortem debugger by `windbg -I` with admin privilege
2. then, forced chrome to crash
3. but windbg can't catch the crash

Comment: what I actually want to do is to have a debugger(windbg or cdb whatever) attach to the chrome process automatically when it crashes.

Comment: it's possible for other browsers like IE to do that. we can have a windbg automatically run and attach to the process when it crashes by postmortem debugging. but i can't find the way for chrome.

Comment: Likely Chrome uses its own unhandled exception handler. That means: the crash is handled by Chrome internally. Depending on the implementation, the process simply exits after the routine was called. Thus the process for not crash from OS perspective and no post mortem debugger is instantiated

Comment: [follow this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44312452/1466046), but create a key named chrome.exe instead of devenv.exe, configure windbg to use [chrome symbol server](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/debugging-on-windows)