# Visual Studio 2019 16.7.5 crash - Nuget

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2019, kendo-asp.net-mvc, nuget-package-restore

When I go to -> tools -> nuget package management -> package management settings -> package sources -> package origins, visual studio 2019 crashes.

how can i solve?
i have already cleared the cache, reset the software, run visual studio as administrator and launched in safe mode. but it still doesn't work.

Visual Studio Community 2019
v. 16.7.5

I need to install 'telerik.reporting.services.webapi' package.

Comment: [debug the crash to see more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44312452/1466046)

Comment: Hi Federico, did the `telerik.reporting.services.webapi` package you mean `Telerik.Reporting` NuGet package? Did you perform some actions on `Package Sources` window? Or you mean after you clicked `Package Sources`, VS 2019 crashes?

 

Did you try to repair VS from VS Installer? Please also try to disable third-party extensions and reboot your machine to test again, and make sure that the nuget.org(https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/) has been added to the Package sources.

Comment: @Federico ,any update about this issue? Please check if my answer helps you handle the issue and let us know any feedback about it. And we will provide any support if you need.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT it doesn't work. VS still crash

Comment: Close VS, try to delete the folder `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxx` and then restart VS to use the initial vs environment.

Comment: When i do this? at the point 2 before restarting VS?

Comment: the following steps are all the suggestions and there is no order about them. Just Close your VS, and try to delete the folder. Then, restart your VS to log back in to your vs to check if  it works.

Answer (score -1):

Try these:

**1)** disable any other third party vs extensions except **Telerik** extensions under **Extensions**-->**Manage Extensions**

**2)** reset all vs settings under **Tools**-->**Import and Export Settings**-->**Reset all settings**

**3)** [clean all nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) or delete all files under `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\.nuget\packages`

**4)** close VS Instance, delete the `nuget.config` file under `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\AppData\Roaming\NuGet` and then reopen VS to regenerate it.

**Then**, add `telerik` nuget source on the nuget package sources under **Tools**-->**Nuget Package Manager**-->**Package Manager Settings**.

add `https://nuget.telerik.com/nuget` as telerik nuget source so that you can access `telerik.reporting.services.webapi`.

like this:

[image]

**Besides**, if you still cannot face the crash issue under **step 4**, please try to [repair vs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) or `devenv.exe / resetuserdata` under `Developer Command Prompt for VS2019`.

**In addition**, you can try to reinstall **Progress Control Panel** under [telerik website with your own account](https://www.telerik.com/account/?_ga=2.81251031.1960982045.1602125278-1118344563.1600760332).

[image]

**Last**,  this is my result:

[image]