# Visual Studio 2012 crashes when deploying SSIS packages

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, ssis

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 to generate SSIS packages using a BIML script, and then deploy them.

It uses metadata from SQL Server and runs a range of scripts eg to (re)generate stored procedures executed by the packages.

One of my 3 solutions (same process for different DBs/ using different metadata) seems to crash every time it comes to deploying the packages.

After selecting the destination server, it loads for a while and then fails. When I tried to click on the failure message hyperlink, Visual Studio 'stopped working unexpectedly'.
Clicking on details for that error message gives me the details below:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: devenv.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 11.0.50727.1
  Problem Signature 03: 5011ecaa
  Problem Signature 04: System.Windows.Forms
  Problem Signature 05: 4.8.4261.0
  Problem Signature 06: 5f4ff3fc
  Problem Signature 07: 2def
  Problem Signature 08: 181
  Problem Signature 09: System.ComponentModel.Win32
  OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.16.7
  Locale ID:    2057
  Additional Information 1: 0d2d
  Additional Information 2: 0d2dbfbe26d8124f405890ad1070c781
  Additional Information 3: 62c8
  Additional Information 4: 62c8123e2e294af45540197344fa44eb

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=280262

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Can anyone help identify the issue here?

I'm not sure if the details above (relating to Visual Studio crashing) indicate what caused the deployment to fail just beforehand or if that's a separate failure.

It nearly always completes successfully on the second attempt, but I'm not sure what the implications of that are.

Comment: create a [crash dump and analyze it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44312452/1466046) to see why VS crashes

Comment: @magicandre1981 - thanks, unfortunately I don't have permissions for that kind of thing. Was hoping the symptoms might be enough to point me in the right direction re changing the process or as evidence I need to request more RAM or something. If it needs to go via the IS team to actually investigate I'll be in for a long wait :(

Comment: there is no other way to debug this issue.

Comment: Project deployment model or package deployment model? aka SSISDB or msdb?

Comment: @billinkc - project deployment/ SSISDB

Answer (score 0):

Check this similar error (with solution) in Visual Studio 2012 on msdn.microsoft.com:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b4e2d299-263b-405d-a19b-42a83d94f612/systemtypeloadexception-in-visual-studio-2012?forum=sqlintegrationservices