# CLR20r3 error while installing Visual Studio Community 2019 - vs_setup_bootstrapper.exe

Tags: visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2019, filenotfoundexception, bootstrapper

I saw a lot of similar questions here but the .exe was different in all cases. I checked all the solutions I was able to apply, however, the problem is still the same. When I download the VS Community 2019, when I run it I automatically got the error that it stopped working, details are as follows:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: CLR20r3

Problem Signature 01: vs_setup_bootstrapper.exe

Problem Signature 02:   2.8.3267.30329
  
Problem Signature 03:   9d2a945d
  
Problem Signature 04:   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup
  
Problem Signature 05:   2.8.3267.30329
  
Problem Signature 06:   f7c67f65
  
Problem Signature 07:   898
  
Problem Signature 08:   10
  
Problem Signature 09:   System.IO.FileNotFoundException
  
OS Version: 6.3.9600.2.0.0.256.49
  
Locale ID:  2057
  
Additional Information 1:   6f38
  
Additional Information 2:   6f383fc314ee72e602c66fef1120ed98
  
Additional Information 3:   ed5f
  
Additional Information 4:   ed5f401470800aa8aa962bbe84af7a8d
```

I tried restarting, uninstalling and installing everything related to .NET, found some cmd-based solutions but the problem is still the same. I Had VS on my PC before, but I decided to reinstall it, and now I am unable to...

My current OS is Windows 8.1 Pro N, 2013 (if that helps in any way :D)

I will appreciate any piece of advice, if there is any information additionally needed, please ask me for it

Comment: do you have all Windows 8.1 updates installed? Also try to install the [Media Pack first](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2929699/media-feature-pack-for-windows-8-1-n-and-windows-8-1-kn-editions-april)

Comment: I have tried, all the updates are installed, I aslo installed the Pack - still the same :(

Comment: capture a [dump](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44312452/1466046) (replace `devenv.exe` with `vs_setup_bootstrapper.exe`) and analyze the dump.

Comment: I think I did it (woah, "I'm not an IT person!") and I got the result which doesn't say much to me, I mean, I don't know how to solve it
The result is too long to paste it here, but maybe the most important here are

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID: CLR_EXCEPTION_NOSOS_80070002_vs_setup_bootstrapper.exe!unknown_function

OS_VERSION:  6.3.9600.18217

BUILDLAB_STR:  winblue_ltsb

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 8.1

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {9c0b5c4c-cfb4-5ab8-4224-cb839c26aaf3}

Are there any ideas what happened? :(

Comment: run **.load sos** first and next analyze. if this is still not helpful use the debug analyzer. I also checked my 8.1 and it is 9600.19893, so I still think you miss updates.

Comment: I tried to write .load sos and got this:
The call to LoadLibrary(sos) failed, Win32 error 0n2
    "The system cannot find the file specified."
Please check your debugger configuration and/or network access.

Comment: try debug analyzer and not windbg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226749/discussion-between-sigma-and-magicandre1981).

Comment: I mean Debug Diagnostic Tool, this in included as 2nd part of my linked answer

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I have changed OS from Win8 to Win10 and was able to install it. Seems like I deleted too many files on my own and was unable to restore it manually

Thank you all for your help! I really appreiate!

Comment: Be glad to know that you have a workaround about your issue. Since you have a workaround, I suggest you could [mark your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) and it will help other community members search and handle similar issues:)

Answer (score 0):

**First**, check the VS2019 installation environment，and just as [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/system-requirements#visual-studio-2019-system-requirements) said, you should install `Update 2919335` for your **Windows 8.1**.

**If** this does not work, please try to run`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout\InstallCleanup.exe`.

It will uninstall all VS IDE(`VS2017` and `VS2019`) and all related components, caches, registry info. Make a strong deep, strong clean.

**Then**, re-download setup program and try to install again.

Comment: I think I spoiled it, as I don't have such a folder at all :P
The update was installed a few times I suppose, same result

Comment: Run the program as `Administrator`, did it work?  The `Installer` is created when you run `vs_community.exe`, did you face the issue once the program pops up? If you have, you should run that program to do a deep clean. If not, please try to delete `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxx`, `C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp`, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community`. then reinstall the installer again.